# AngularJS: How to ng-repeat from specific value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a template that will repeat based on certain value. For example if the total number of pages are 3 and total records are 15 then each page will have 5 records. So essentially it would be a nested ng-repreat.

I create a sample java code

```
int index = 1;
for(int i =1; i <=5; i++){
   System.out.print("#"+i);
   for(int j = index; j<=14; j++){
      System.out.print("->"+index);
      index++;
      if(j%3==0){
         break;
      }
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

These will correctly set number of records of each page. 
Now I need to first create templates pages based on the how many pages I will need and then inside each page I need a particular number of records.
In angular its a bit tricky to write this logic using ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="i in X" >
   <div>
      <div ng-repeat="j in Y">
         <span></span>
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split X into chunks of the desired size (5) to make it an array of arrays. Then iterate over it and iterate over the inner array as well.

Assume you want one item per page instead of five:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.X = items.reduce((chunks, item) => {
  chunks.push([item]);
  return chunks;
}, []);
```

Now you can use `ng-repeat="chunk in X"` and you can then use `ng-repeat="item in chunk"` internally.